# how to delete .part1.rar, part01.rar etc when only the extension is known

Tags: batch-file

this bit of code is supposed to delete the successfully extracted archive(s), first of which is the known `%fullpath%\%file%.%exe%`. it uses the `???` wildcards so it deletes multiparts like `.7z.001`, `.zip.001` and `.r01`, but it cannot do multiparts like `.part1.rar, .part01.rar, .part001.rar`.

```
echo successfully unpacked "%fullpath%\%file%.%ext%"
attrib -r "%fullpath%\%file%.???"
for /r "%fullpath%" %%r in (%file%.???) do del "%%r" && echo deleted "%%r"
```

Comment: What about a pattern like `*.*.rar` or `*.part*.rar`?

Comment: I have to use the `%file%` variable and the problem is that it includes the `.part###` part, making it a bad keyword for all the numbers. I can't not use the `%file%` variable because its too vague, there might be different archives in the folder. sorry for the double negative.

Comment: You could check if the `%file%` part contains another `.` by `for %%Z in ("%filename%") do if "%%~xZ" (set "pattern=%%~nZ.*.%ext%") else (set "pattern=%file%.*")` and use `%pattern%` instead of `%file%.???` then...

Comment: What is the reason for using `attrib` and a `for` loop? You could probably do this directly with the `del` command, e.g. `Del /F /S /Q /A *.rar *.r01 *.001 …`.

Comment: because of the need to `echo` each one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it

```
echo unpacked "%fullpath%\%file%.%ext%"
attrib -r "%fullpath%\*.*" /s
:: maybe a little more concern here? also deletes every other filetype with the same name
for /r "%fullpath%" %%r in (%file%.??? %file:~0,-6%.part?.rar %file:~0,-7%.part??.rar %file:~0,-8%.part???.rar) do (
    if exist "%%r" del "%%r" >nul 2>nul && echo deleted extracted archive "%%r")
```